# Project Management courses

Tags: pmp

I have just completed my three years in project management role. I have contributed five projects towards successful delivary and achieved targets on time. I have been told to pursue management courses for my career growth and knowledge.

Can you guide me through pmp prince2 agile scrum and other project management courses at beginner level ?

Comment: Welcome to PMSE. As it stands, your question is too broad. Please modify or it risks being deleted. Refer to the sites FAQs for further guidance on asking questions.

Comment: Okay i understood my question is broad. Here is my question, PMP and Prince 2 course they are totally different management courses in reality. I work in ITeS environment and have just started reading PMBOK book as a guide for my problems, risks in my project and methodoligies to deal with. My colleagues choose prince2 but i am finding pmp more prominent as Benefits of pmp over prince2 are : Better Salary aspects, Networking opportunities, Better Employment Prospects more importantly pmp involves management and delivery of project while prince2 involves execution of project.

Comment: My question to the experts in PM. So am i in wrong track ?

Comment: Are you seeking knowledge and skill growth or certificates?

Comment: Yes i am preparing for PMP exam next year. And yes inclusion of improvement in knowledge and skills too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your primary objective is a certificate and your objectives of knowledge acquisition and skill mastery are secondary, then the certificate dictates what you need to study.  Research the PMI website and obtain and read the PMBoK.  The PMBoK will steer you to the knowledge and process areas you need to learn and then you can find those courses, sign up, and take them.  There are many PMI-approved vendors out there that provide this education; however, many of them teach to the test.  Since your time frame is a year out, I suggest you find courses that teach the content instead of how to pass the test.  Because that will help you meet your secondary goals.

If knowledge and skill mastery were your objectives, then your two questions you need to answer are: 1) in what are you interested that you may wish to seek a specialty and 2) in what areas are you demonstrably weak?

These answers will dictate your next set of courses.

Since you're just beginning, I'd suggest to reverse your objectives.

Comment: Yes i will do accordingly. Gain knowledge and improve skills through the PMBoK then join a pmi registered course center for guidance throughout the test. Thanks!